# Why is the end of a file is not found, when moving the chars?

Tags: c, file, eof

I try to output a files content, but I need to add +20 to each char, because the characters in the file are moved by -20. Outputting the content works but reaching the end of a file, `Ù`is printed in a loop. Can anyone help me with my code?

```
    while ((holder = (fgetc(dateiGlob)-ENC_NUM)) != EOF) // ENC_Num = 20
    {
        if (holder == ';') // Replace ; 
        {
            printf("\n");
            holder = '\0';
        }

        if (holder == '/') // Replace /
        {
            printf(" | Anmerkung: ");
            holder = '\0';
        }

        putchar(holder); // Print in stdout
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

When ENC_NUM is set to 0, EOF is found again.
What do I need to change?
Thank you!

Comment: Because `EOF - ENC_NUM` != `EOF`.

Comment: Also remember that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**, which is important for the `EOF` comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefuly at your while condition.

```
(fgetc(dateiGlob) - ENC_NUM) != EOF
```

If you set `ENC_NUM = 0`, the condition becomes `fgetc(dateiGlob) != EOF`, which is what you need in order to stop reading the file when you're at its end.

Now, if you want to change the left side of the condition (by making `ENC_NUM` a non-zero integer), you also need to change its right side in the same way (in order to preserve the logic):

```
(fgetc(dateiGlob) - ENC_NUM) != (EOF - ENC_NUM)
//                ^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh, how could I oversee this! Thanks !

Comment: `(fgetc(dateiGlob) - ENC_NUM) != (EOF - ENC_NUM)`.  That's not guaranteed to work.  `EOF` is defined as an `int` with negative value that can not represent a `char` value.  There's no guarantee that `EOF - 20` is not a valid `char` value, causing the loop to end prematurely.  Also, there's no guarantee that `EOF - 20` doesn't produce underflow and therefor undefined behavior.  Shift the `char` value by 20 **after** checking it against `EOF`.